# How do I know the structure about avc3 of mp4 box?

Tags: mp4, mp4parser

I've got some tools of analyzing mp4 stream such as Mp4 Explorer, MP4 Reader and mp4viewer(by python).
None of them can show what structure avc3 has But I can see avc1.
So I've been looking avc3 from ISO-ISE 14496-12, QuickTime format(from apple's doc) and finding avc1 and avcC.
While searching, somebody who works with things like demuxer has left a commit message like 'mp4 box with avc3 support now'.
But that's all :( Where can I find and see a reference document?

Does anyone know about avc3?

Answer (score 7):

The sample description entry 'avc3' is structurally identical to the 'avc1'. The difference is only in the semantics: in 'avc3' streams the parameter sets can be in band, in the IDR samples. You can find the definition in ISO/IEC 14496-15 3rd edition.

Comment: appreciating your awesome answer!